# Как добавить версионирование json файлов в Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

В Laravel v5.5 (back-end) генерируются порядка ста `*.json` файлов, к которым буду обращаться на клиентской стороне (front-end). Необходимо добавить версионирование этих файлов.

Я изменил файл `webpack.mix.js` таким образом:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
  .setPublicPath('public/build')
  .setResourceRoot('build')
  .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'css')
  // .json('resources/assets/json/*', 'json')
  .version();
```

При выполнении команды `npm run dev` с методом `.json(...)` получаю ошибку о том, что `.json(...)` не является функцией.

Как выполнить копирование из *resources/assets/json/* в *public/build/* всех файлов `*.json` с добавлением хеша в файле *mix-manifest.json* также как это делается для `*.js` и `*.css` файлов:

```
{
  "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js?id=1201bfb6e0c7cc454cde",
  "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css?id=dec12e109f69d0aea8d2"
}
```

---

Не знаю как это реализовать. Есть варианты?

Comment: я это использовал но он не добавляет версионирование mix-manifest.json пустой массив создается(

Comment: 5.5 версию использую

Comment: нашел такой вариант, через копи использую таким образом .copy('resources/assets/json/r17-c1.json', 'public/build/json/r17-c1.json'), но этот вариант даст только один файл и mix-manifest.json файле тоже изменился(добавился хэш), но как я вытащу все файлы, если там добавляются файлы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть такой рабочий вариант, проверен на Laravel v5.8 и [Laravel Mix](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/master/versioning) v4.1.2:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
  .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
  // Копируем директорию с файлами.
  .copyDirectory('resources/json', 'public/json');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
  // Передаем массив путей с файлами или папками,
  // для которых нужно дополнительно установить версионирование.
  mix.version([
    'public/json'
  ]);
}
```

**NB**: не забудьте поменять пути к папкам на свои.

---

**Недостаток**: Mix не дожидается, когда папка с файлами скопируется, поэтому приходится дважды запускать `npm run production`. Использование метода `.then()` не решает эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

сделал так:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix
    .setPublicPath('public/build')
    .setResourceRoot('build')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'css')
    .copyDirectory('resources/assets/json', 'public/build/json')
    .version(['public/build/json']);
```

и два раза `npm run dev`, после этого работает нормально